# Calculating the missing two points of rectangle if 2 points and the aspect ratio are known

Tags: linear-algebra, rectangles

How can I calculate the missing two points of a rectangle if I know 2 points (top left and top right) and the aspect ratio i.e 16:10.

For example: Top left: A(834, 449) and Top right: B(1675, 423)

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate all the points of a rectangle"? Also, it seems that your points are not points as in geometry, but pixels.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I'm working with images. For the simplicity we can use any coordinatesfor A and B. By all points I mean the missing two which are C and D.

Comment: So your two points are not aligned ? They don't have the same $y$ coordinate ? Not saying it's wrong but a bit weird considering the context.

Comment: @Meetz: You should probably also tell us which corner is considered to be $(0,0)$.

Comment: I think that it's okay to assume that the points are aligned, because the rectangle in my case can't be pixel perfect.

Comment: @Alex M. What do you mean exactly? The starting point? That would be the top left corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider the vector of the width of your rectangle $\vec{AB} = (841,-26)$. According to the aspect ratio the "height-vector" will be perpendicular to $\vec{AB}$. So it will be of the form $10/16 \cdot (26,841) = \vec{v}$. Now you can add $B + \vec{v}$ and get $C$ and $A + \vec{v} = D$.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you. May I know how you came up with the solution? I'd like to understand this better.

Comment: @Meetz Well it's "simply" some [analytic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_geometry). You gave some numbers as coordinates so clearly we had to think with points and vectors. First thing that came to my mind is to compute $\vec{AB}$ since that's the only information we really have. Then I thought of how to rotate at $90°$ this vectors and also of what will its length be. "Drawing" a small diagram in my head and voilà :)